# I need to enable new divs on the page to be viewed by the DOM after ajax content recieved

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, what I have is a page where there is a whole lot of ajax happening.

Ajax loads a products table. Within the table are various buttons to update and to delete items. These buttons don't work unless I nest a $(document).ready inside the success function.

How do I get the page reloading so that the new elements can be viewed and accessed?

I can't use window.reload() as this completely refreshes the whole page back to its original state. Whereas I only want the newly added ajax content to be able to be used with more ajax

Here is what my code looks like at the moment...

```
$('#viewProductButton').click(function() {
                //$('#subSubCat').hide();
                //var id = $(this).val();
                var subID = document.getElementById("subCategory").value;
                var subSubID = document.getElementById("subSubCat").value;
                $.ajax({
                url: 'products/viewProdTable/'+subID+'/'+subSubID,
                success: function(data) {
                    // display results table of user selected products
                    $('#viewProducts').fadeIn(100, function(){
                        $(this).html(data);
                    })
                }
                }); // end ajax
            });`
```

So after my new data is entered into #viewProducts, it has some buttons that will utilise ajax to perform other functions. They wont work unless I put a doc.ready inside the #viewProducts function.

Is there something else I can do as I will keep having all these nested doc.ready functions as the page is very interactive.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: jquery on will work for you http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your initial page load script and it will bind the click to the element whether it was there from the start or dynamically added via ajax :)

```
 $('body').on('click' , '#viewProductButton' , function() {
 // Do stuff....
 });
```

You can see how to lay it out, so just change the element ID to whatever element you would like to bind the click to, and you can change the ' click' to whatever you need, like ' hover' or ' change' and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your new buttons don't have event handlers bound. Most likely your doc.ready does the binding.

You need to add them or use a delegate in your doc.ready function:

[jquery web site has example of this](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

try this $('#viewProductButton').live('click',function() { alert("do your work"); })

Comment: Live has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: So I use this within the doc.ready() or within the function I orginally posted?